# Android screen coordinates

Tags: android, screen, coordinates

I am testing my application with Eclipse Android Emulator. Everything is fine except that the 0,0 coordinates are at the center of the screen not top left as it is expected.
For example: 
the statement 
canvas.drawBitmap(ball, 0, 0, mPaint);
will display/draw a ball on the center of screen instead of the top left corner.
I would appreciate any ideas on how to handle this issue or is this normal?
The canvas.getHeight() and canvas.getWidth() statements return the correct result though (480X800)

Many thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code, are you using any matrix transforms, is the bitmap and canvas at the same densities etc.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you're trying to draw this ball in some other inner view, which is centred..

Comment: I was using translate, now it's fixed.